# Regex pattern to find a term's existence in last 3 words of another term in a string

Tags: c#, regex

Need to write RegEx in C# for the below req.

**Input - A String, Term 1 (No), Term 2 (Alcohol)**

I want to find out, if a term like "not" is present in last 2 or 3 words before  term like "alcohol".

```
1. String : I am not taking alcohol these days.
```

Answer - Yes

```
2. String : I am not feeling like taking alcohol these days.
```

Answer - No

I tried something like below, but its not working :

```
Regex.IsMatch(textLine, @"(^|\s)" + negativeTerm + @"(\s|$)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

Comment: Do your terms always contain only word chars (letters, digits, and `_`)? You are using whitespace boundaries a bit wrong and the pattern is just not doing what you need.

Comment: I think it is enough to use [`(?i)\bnot\W+(?:\w+\W+){0,2}alcohol\b`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cbnot%5cW%2b%28%3f%3a%5cw%2b%5cW%2b%29%7b0%2c2%7dalcohol%5cb&i=Not+alcohol!+Again...%0d%0aI+am+not+taking+alcohol+these+days.%0d%0aI+am+not+feeling+like+taking+alcohol+these+days.&o=i).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regex should do the job:

```
//var textLine = "I am not taking alcohol these days.";
var textLine = "I am not feeling like taking alcohol these days";
var negativeTerm = "not";
var searchedTerm = "Alcohol";

var matched = Regex.IsMatch(textLine, $@"\b{negativeTerm}\W+(?:\w+\W+){{1,2}}?{searchedTerm}\b", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Comment: This works for last 1 or 2 terms. But this is not working for 0th or 3rd terms if I add the same way {{0,1,2,3}}  Any idea what I am missing

Comment: In this regex {1,2} is not a term index. It's a quantifier that require that there should be min 1 and max 2 words between negative term and searched term. That's what you asked for. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Makes sense, let me try 0-4..I was testing some ranges thanks